# How to use onmouseover and onmouseout to hide and unhide a button when the mouse goes over it?

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, onmouseout

When the mouse goes over the button i want it to hide and when the mouse goes off the button i want the button to reappear. But i need to use onmouseover and onmouseout.

```js
<script>
function money ()
{
 document.getElementById("1").style.display = "none";
}

function cash ()
{
 document.getElementById("1").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Hi" id="1" onmouseover="money('')" onmouseout="cash('')" >
```

Comment: Take a look at the docs to see how you can use those events: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/ will give you the answer you need @Mike

Comment: Sounds like a great way to trick users ?

Comment: i want to do this in java script and html. Nothing else

Comment: Use visibility:visible and visibility:hidden instead of display:block/none, because when you display:none the element, the element will be removed from the DOM, the page will reflow, the mouse will be counted as being moved off of it, the element will be re-added, and then the mouse will enter it again...

Comment: You also might consider doing this in CSS. The entire CSS would be `input[type=button]:hover { visibility: hidden; }`. Note that ids can't start with numbers and be valid in CSS (or maybe you just need to escape it somehow?).

Comment: @AgentME ok thnks but i want to try in javascript. also what would i put in the cash function.?

Comment: <script>
function money ()
{
 document.getElementById("1").style.visibility = "hidden";
}

function cash ()
{
 document.getElementById("1").style.visibility = "";
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="Hi" id="1" onmouseover="money('')" onmouseout="cash('')" >

Answer (score 1):

As you already know, this can he done using CSS's `:hover`...
**but here's a JS way:**

```js
function money (el){
 el.style.opacity = 0;
}

function cash (el){
 el.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Hi" onmouseenter="money(this)" onmouseleave="cash(this)">
```

So yes, use `opacity`, `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` and pass the `this` (HTMLElement) reference.

To recap, opacity will visually "hide" the element but keep it in place, not triggering a `mouseleave` due to element disappearance.

---

I'd also highly **discourage** you from using **inline JS**,
keep all your logic where's it's meant to be: **inside your `script`**:

```js
function tog(event) {
  this.style.opacity = event.type==="mouseenter" ? 0 : 1;
}

var btn1 = document.getElementById("1");
btn1.addEventListener("mouseenter", tog);
btn1.addEventListener("mouseleave", tog);
```

```html
<input id="1" type="button" value="Hi">
```

**Note that** you button will still be clickable :)
If you don't want it to be clickable, **target a parent element instead**, than you can use `display: "none"/""` on your button children.

Comment: Oh, I guess toggling visibility wasn't quite right. That still causes the same flickering issue (though without reflowing the rest of the page at least).

Comment: @AgentME fixed using `opacity`

Answer (score 1):

here is the pure JS way: Note that the button like the other answer will flutter:
https://jsfiddle.net/omarjmh/6o2nc754/1/

```
var x = document.getElementById("myBtn");
x.addEventListener("mouseenter", myFunction);
x.addEventListener("mouseout", mySecondFunction);

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
}

function mySecondFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: same flattering/flickering issue at least in Chrome.. hummmm

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when the cursor enters the button then the mouseover event is fired, the element disappears, the mouseout event fires because the element is gone and thus the mouse isn't in it any more. You need to put the button in a div and do the mouse out on that div.